# Android Emulator does not start and gives following errors

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, emulation

I tried to start the emulator first time on my laptop and it shows the following error I am working on Windows 7 (64 bit) and android Studio version 1.2.2

```
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inodes per group: 4224
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inode size: 256
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Journal blocks: 1024
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
```

Comment: Does it start for the second time?

Comment: I also tried making a new virtual device and changing its system image to google Inc

Comment: @BidhanA Well if it starts for the second time I wouldn't be posting here! Anyways that was freaking title I gave... Its all because its not working and messing up my time

Comment: Yeah well your title was confusing. This problem arises due to issues with your graphics card. What card do you have?

Comment: @BidhanA I have integrated Intel HD Graphics 4000 and switchable AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series

Comment: Open your AMD Catalyst Control Center and assign your emulator to the Radeon instead of the integreated graphics card.

Comment: @BidhanA Well I have assigned studio.exe and studio64.exe both  radeon card and restarted the program and relaunched the emulator still gives the same error. Also assigning default Intel Graphic card.. It also gives the same error

Comment: You need to assign the emulator, not Android Studio. Android Studio and emulator are two different things.

Comment: @BidhanA How can I find the file for emulator to select? When I click on add application in my catalyst controller it allows me to browse files than I visited the directory of installed studio and selected both of them. I tried to search some file with emulator but didnt find any in bin, gradle, lib, licence, or plugins folder. How should I do than?